# JBoss 7.1.1.Final - EJB Remote Call - java.lang.IllegalStateException: No EJB receiver available for handling

Tags: ejb, jboss7.x, remote-access, illegalstateexception

I do have 2 JBoss stanalon instance running. 1 act as Server and another 1 would client.

**SERVER:**

**Remote Interface**

```java
package com.xyz.life.service.ejb;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface QuoteFacade extends Serializable{
    public boolean isAlive()    throws RemoteException;
}
```

**EJB Impl**

```java
package com.xyz.life.common.component.ejb.services;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless(mappedName = "QuoteFacadeEJB")
@Remote(QuoteFacade.class)
public class QuoteFacadeEJB extends CommonSessionBean implements QuoteFacade {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8788783322280644881L;

    @Override
    public boolean isAlive() throws RemoteException {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**server.log**

```
16:40:25,012 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named QuoteFacadeEJB in deployment unit subdeployment "quote.jar" of deployment "quote.ear" are as follows:
        java:global/quote/quote.jar/QuoteFacadeEJB!com.xyz.life.service.ejb.QuoteFacade
        java:app/quote.jar/QuoteFacadeEJB!com.xyz.life.service.ejb.QuoteFacade
        java:module/QuoteFacadeEJB!com.xyz.life.service.ejb.QuoteFacade
        java:jboss/exported/quote/quote.jar/QuoteFacadeEJB!com.xyz.life.service.ejb.QuoteFacade
        java:global/quote/quote.jar/QuoteFacadeEJB
        java:app/quote.jar/QuoteFacadeEJB
        java:module/QuoteFacadeEJB
```

**Client**

```java
public void testClient() {
        try {
            Hashtable<String, Object> jndiProps = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
            jndiProps.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, JNDINames.JBOSS_CLIENT_NAMING_PREFIX);
            jndiProps.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
            Context ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProps);

            String name = "ejb:global/quote/quote.jar/QuoteFacadeEJB!com.ge.life.annuity.service.ejb.QuoteFacade";
            /*
            "ejb:global/quote/quote.jar/QuoteFacadeEJB!com.ge.life.annuity.service.ejb.QuoteFacade",
            "ejb:app/quote.jar/QuoteFacadeEJB!com.ge.life.annuity.service.ejb.QuoteFacade",
            "ejb:jboss/exported/quote/quote.jar/QuoteFacadeEJB!com.ge.life.annuity.service.ejb.QuoteFacade"
            */

            Object ref = ctx.lookup(name);
            QuoteFacade quoteFacade = (QuoteFacade) ref;
            LOGGER.debug("isAlive : " + quoteFacade.isAlive());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Remote Client Exception : ", e);
        }
    }
```

**No error/log on server side. Client side, it is failing with following error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:global,modulename:quote,distinctname:quote.jar] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@200cae

    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:584)

    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:119)

    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181)

    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:136)

    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:121)

    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:104)

    at $Proxy10.isAlive(Unknown Source)
```

**I tried without using Properties file:**

```java
private static QuoteFacade connectToStatelessBean(String name) throws NamingException {  

        Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();  
        jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");  
        jndiProperties.put(javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");  
        jndiProperties.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");  
        jndiProperties.put(javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "admin");  
        jndiProperties.put(javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "Pass1234");  
        final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);  

        return (QuoteFacade) context.lookup(name);  
    }  
    public static void testLocal() {  
        String[] JNDINAME1 = {  

        "ejb:global/quote/quote.jar/QuoteFacadeEJB!com.ge.life.annuity.service.ejb.QuoteFacade",  
        "ejb:app/quote.jar/QuoteFacadeEJB!com.ge.life.annuity.service.ejb.QuoteFacade",  
        "ejb:module/QuoteFacadeEJB!com.ge.life.annuity.service.ejb.QuoteFacade",  
        "ejb:jboss/exported/quote/quote.jar/QuoteFacadeEJB!com.ge.life.annuity.service.ejb.QuoteFacade",  
        "ejb:global/quote/quote.jar/QuoteFacadeEJB",  
        "ejb:app/quote.jar/QuoteFacadeEJB",  
        "ejb:module/QuoteFacadeEJB"  
    };  
    for(int i=0;i<JNDINAME1.length;i++){  
        try {  
            QuoteFacade test1 = connectToStatelessBean(JNDINAME1[i]);  
            LOGGER.error("DSLKAJDLAS : " + test1.isAlive());  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            LOGGER.error("DSLKAJDLAS : " , e);  
        }  

    }  
    LOGGER.info("Done - SANSSAN!!!!!!!!");  
}
```

**This time, different exception :**

```
14.01.2013 17:40:37.627 [ERROR] - EJBClient - DSLKAJDLAS :   
javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.quote.war:main" from Service Module Loader  
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactoryBuilder.createInitialContextFactory(InitialContextFactoryBuilder.java:64)  
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:681)  
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)  
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)  
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.><init>(InitialContext.java:216)  
    at com.xyz.life.test.EJBClient.connectToStatelessBean(EJBClient.java:208)  
    at com.xyz.life.test.EJBClient.testLocal(EJBClient.java:225)  
    at com.xyz.life.test.EJBClient.test(EJBClient.java:172)  
    at com.xyz.life.common.web.struts.plugin.FrameworkStartupPlugIn.init(FrameworkStartupPlugIn.java:99)  
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:1158)  
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:473)  
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873)  
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90)  
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)  
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing "global" from `name`:

```
String name =
  "ejb:quote/quote.jar/QuoteFacadeEJB!com.xyz.life.service.ejb.QuoteFacade"
```

Also, your package name should be `com.xyz.life.service.ejb` (as seen on server log) and not `com.ge.life.annuity.service.ejb`.

Anyway, using remote-naming project for remote EJB invocations is discouraged as explained [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project).

> ... . So as you can see, we have managed to optimize certain operations by using the EJB client API for EJB lookup/invocation as against using the remote-naming project. There are other EJB client API implementation details (and probably more might be added) which are superior when it is used for remote EJB invocations in client applications as against remote-naming project which doesn't have the intelligence to carry out such optimizations for EJB invocations. That's why the remote-naming project for remote EJB invocations is considered "deprecated". ...

You can check how to do remote EJB invocations using the EJB client API [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI).

Answer (score 0):

Found it....

The ones I used for Local machines only. Difference JBoss instances, should change the JNDI lookup name...

like

```
ejb:quote/quote.jar//QuoteFacadeEJB!com.xyz.life.service.ejb.QuoteFacade
```

Comment: You don't even look into my answer do you?